# NetBeans doesn't want to build (import) Android support lib

Tags: java, android, netbeans

I use NetBeans and don't want to switch to Eclipse cause of this but it really gets on my nerves. I imported support.v4.app.NavUtils and it still says it can't find it. Here's the picture. Please help me!
[image]

P.S. Sorry if it's trivial problem.

Comment: Have you cleaned your project? Try to choose Run > Clean and Build Project (Shift-F11).

Comment: Yes, I did. Same thing happens.

Comment: Made sure that it is 'checked' in Project Properties -> Libraries? (right click the project -> Properties, on windows).

Comment: You mean Libraries or JAR Libraries? If you mean only Libraries, there's nothing there I can 'check' and can't open it there. If you mean JAR Libraries, I marked "custom location" and opened v4 directory and than clicked on android-support-v4.jar in "Referenced JAR Libraries" when it showed up. What else I can do? Btw, I'm using NetBeans 7.3.1

Comment: My suggestion is to file a bug at https://bitbucket.org/nbandroid/nbandroid/issues and attach a test case (see tips in http://nbandroid.org/wiki/index.php/Contacts ).